# How to create a mint account on anchor test?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, anchor-test, mint

It would be extremely useful if I could create a mint account from a JSON file to test my anchor program.

I have this in my `Anchor.toml` to add the account when I run `anchor test`

```
[[test.validator.account]]
address = "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v"
filename = "tests/seeds/EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v.json"
```

In the json file I would like to have a spl-token mint but I don't know the fields I should add, I tried this:

```
{
    "pubkey": "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v",
    "account": {
        "lamports": 146540070945,
        "data": [
            "AQAAABzjWe1aAS4E+hQrnHUaHF6Hz9CgFhuchf/TG3jN/Nj2j72OKE7jEQAGAQEAAAAqnl7btTwEZ5CY/3sSZRcUQ0/AjFYqmjuGEQXmctQicw==",
            "base64"
        ],
        "owner": "HzYyRXzKNdTc5rnY9kasVAxvs2j2zDLQRbEk1VnX6KAk",
        "executable": false,
        "rentEpoch": 335
    }
}
```

Is there an example of a mint account that is initialized from a JSON file?

Answer (score 2):

If you are intending to test much of SPL related logic within your smart contract, you can set it up for each test manually. This is (roughly) the script I used at the start of my test file. It is quite old and may be out of date as much of the syntax changes almost weekly.

```
import {
    createMint,
    createAccount,
    getAccount,
    getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
    transfer,
    mintTo,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

describe("Tests", async () => {
    // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
    anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());
    const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.local();
    const LAMPORTS_PER_SOL = 1000000000;            
    const person1 = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();                
    const PaYeR = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    const mintAuthSC = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();    
    const mintKeypairSC = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();            
    let mintSC: PublicKey;           
    let person1ATA;               
    
    before(async () => {
        // SOL Top-ups for all accounts used
        {        
            await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
                await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
                    PaYeR.publicKey,
                    2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
                )
            );
            await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
                await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
                    mintAuthSC.publicKey,
                    2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
                )
            );
            await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(
                await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
                    person1.publicKey,
                    2 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
                )
            );  
        }
    
        // Stablecoin mint
        mintSC = await createMint(
            provider.connection,
            PaYeR,
            mintAuthSC.publicKey,
            mintAuthSC.publicKey,
            10,
            mintKeypairSC,
            undefined,
            TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        ); 
        
        // Initialise ATA
        person1ATA = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            provider.connection,
            PaYeR,
            mintSC,
            person1.publicKey
        ); 
        
        // Top up test account with SPL
        await mintTo(
            provider.connection,
            PaYeR,
            mintSC,
            person1ATA.address,
            mintAuthSC,
            100,
            [],
            undefined,
            TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        );
    });
        

    it("TEST 1", async () => {
        <YOUR UNIT TEST THAT INTERACTS WITH SPL-PROGRAM>
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this documentation. This might help.

> https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-mint-nfts-on-solana-using-rust-and-metaplex-f66bac717cb8